# Why does Mongo Compass give me the error "$add only supports numeric or date types, not string" when I'm not using `$add`

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-compass

I'm getting a bizarre error in Mongo Compass (v1.2.1) with Mongo version 4.2.8

I have a simple aggregation pipeline step that compares a date and checks an equality.

However I get an unexplainable error saying: `"$add only supports numeric or date types, not string"`

I'm not even using `$add`!

Further, if I modify the second part of the expression, I get a different error saying `unknown top level operator: $eq`, when I can see [in the docs that it clearly is](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/)

[image: Mongo Compass Error]
[image]

Comment: What happens when you use those queries in mongo shell?

Comment: In my NodeJS app that runs it I got no errors, but I'll try in the shell too, didn't think of that before

Comment: Also reference compass docs that say that in that field you can enter arbitrary JS.

Comment: I've managed to isolate the issue at least.. it works when I replace `i_when_max` in the document with `new Date()`. Seems it doesn't like something about the format that comes out of the way `i_when_max` is generated...